# Intellij Idea Error: kotlin-compiler.jar is missing

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

In my project I just did refactor->rename on my one of the Java classes and it broked. How can I fix this issue?
[image: screenshot of the errors]

Comment: Does it help if you reinstall the IDE from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html ?

Comment: I don't need to reinstall the IDE, I just had to create new project.